# Problemas com o tipo de dados

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

O meu site esta a aparecer assim
http://www.adota-me.tk/anuncio.php?id_anuncio=1454792030

Com alguns caracteres estranhos.
Vou referir tudo o que coloquei.

No php esta:

```
 ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');
 header('Content-type: text/html; charset-UTF-8');
```

Agora no PHPMYADMIN, a base de dados está definida como `utf8_bin`, e os dados nas colunas estão definidos como `latin1_general_ci` para cada campo.

O que esta errado para que funcione com `^~` e outros acentos da lingua portuguesa?

Comment: Sugiro que você altere o collate do banco para um só, use o utf8_general_ci, tanto para colunas como para para a base de dados, se não isso poderá lhe trazer dor de cabeça, verifique tambem na meta tag qual charset esta sendo definido.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: Porque vc não tenta igualar o collate do banco e das colunas pra ver como fica..

Comment: funciounou, apesar de o phpmyadmin mostrar caracteres estranhos no php isso nao é mais visivel